# What is the difference between a reminder and an event in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Upon clicking on the plus sign in the Android Google Calendar app, I am offered with the choice to either create an **Event** or a **Reminder**.

What is the exact difference between the two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had read about this in Google forums I think but can't locate. However [here](http://thetechportal.in/2015/12/08/google-calendar-gets-reminders/) is an article that explains the difference. More details in the article

> Google explains that the difference between Events and Reminders is that the former is deleted irrespective of whether the event was attended or not. Reminders on the other hand shows up in Calendar until the task is accomplished — and yea, that’s pretty much the literature difference between the two, so nothing new here Google!
>
> Until a reminder is completed users will be notified of the task by a message displayed on top of Google Calendar. Once the user has finished the task, the reminder can be swiped away from notification area. If you feel that this is a bit irritating then you can set the Reminder to a later time, similar to Events.

Aside, this doesn't work well on my Huawei Honor 6 running KitKat, with reminders getting skipped often- I didn't bother to investigate further

Comment: I still have previous events, they weren't deleted, so this is factually wrong.

Comment: @Santropedro: Thanks. If I come across a latter definition from authentic sources will post it or you if find, please post

Comment: Thanks for taking my criticism so kindly, I'll post here if I ever understand their core differences. As I'm seeing google calendar now, past events  are "greyed" with lighter color. I can see them and even delete them individually.

Comment: @Santropedro: It is important to be right and correct and welcome corrections. But I am surprised that no one pointed this out and it got a fair share of upvotes

Answer (score 2):

In Android 6 I can see that reminders have less possible configuration options. They both share *Name*, *Location* and *start time*, while they differ in:

Reminder:

- One alarm

Event

- Date and time of the end of the event
- Contacts in the event
- Zero or more alarms
- Notes

Comment: Another difference seems to be that reminders lack the ability to send you an email, unfortunately. (WHAT were they thinking??)

Answer (score 1):

To keep my Calendar Events and Reminders clear, I tend to think of calendar events as a fixed time and/or place, where reminders are flexible in the “manditoryness”, time, or place to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I use "Events" for date/time specific happenings, and enjoy the fact that they stay listed, and can serve as a record of how I spent my time that day (I tend to delete things I don't end up doing).  "Reminders" are cool, bc first of all they have a little finger with a string around it as the icon, and I set them to appear when I want to have my memory jogged about something that needs to be done (serves me kind of like a post-it note): i.e., set out the trash barrels, buy a birthday gift for my niece, etc.
Where I think the mix-up can happen, is that Events can be listed, and within the entry box one can set a reminder notification to pop-up 10 min, 30min, 1 hour before the actual event start time.