# Get daily notifications, but invisible on Google Calendar

Tags: notifications, google, calendar

Ok,this is going to sound silly, but I want my calendar to notify/remind me everyday at the same time to take my vitamins, but I don't want to see "take prenatal vitamin" on every square on my calendar app because I use it for actual appointments, etc.

I downloaded aCalendar, but everything I add to that or Google calendar bounces to the other one like automatic syncing. I was hoping to add only the vitamin reminder to the aCalendar and just getting the notifications from it then continuing to utilize the Google Calendar as I have been doing.

Please help!

Comment: don't think there's a way to do this on Google calendar, I believe the way you suggested for yourself is probably the best way to go about it.

Comment: setting it as [event](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/140575/131553) is another alternative

Comment: @beeshyams I believe it still shows up on Google Calendar though

Comment: you can have an automation app send you a notifcation at fixed time (s) and keep your calendar clean