# Push notification a certain date

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calendar, google-calendar, push-notifications

I want to have a push notification a certain date. Google calendar lets me create "reminders", but I do not even see those in the app "Calendar" or the app "Google Calendar", even if the latter shows me an option to show or hide reminders. It also seeme like reminders fail to deliver push notifications.

What a reminder seems to be is a calendar event that shows up in the web version of google calendar and after it has happened, it moves forward to the current day until it is dismissed. There is also an email sent to my gmail account that reminds me, but I have no plans syncing my emails to my phone.

Comment: That is the [expected behaviour of reminder](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/140575/131553) but a recent current says it's not happening. IDK why. Possibly you can look at automation as an option if reminders are not working as expected

Comment: What is automation then?

Comment: I was thinking of Macrodroid situation but that deals with events not reminders unfortunately. You could probably edit your question to indicate that you are open for automation solutions and see what comes up

Comment: What's the difference between a "reminder" and a "normal calendar event" for you? And why must it be a ***push*** notification (i.e. one initiated from "somewhere else" and sent via cloud messaging) – wouldn't a "local notification" do as well? Maybe you could [edit] your question and include what you're trying to achieve, instead of asking how to make your suggested solution work (see: [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154))?

Comment: A push notification is delivered even if the app is not running. When I create a calendar event on google calendars webpage, I can choose between "event" and "reminder" (so there are two types of calendar events). What I want to achieve is to get notified the day a reminder occurs as an entry in the list of notifications.