# Google Calender: Prevent the notification of an event disappearing after the event time?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

Say, I have set a monthly event at a specific time and date on Google Calender. I have enabled "1 minute before" notification for it. The notification shows up at the expected time, but if I happen to be doing something else and think I will do the event later, after that time, the event notification automatically disappears from the phone, even though I have not swiped it out. This sometimes makes me forget that I should do the event.

Is there a way to make the event notification NOT go away even after the time of the event, until I manually swipe it out?

Answer (score 1):

That's the [designed behavior](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/2545848/mobile-alerts-disappear?hl=en) of events and Google Calender doesn't provide a way to keep notification alive.

You can instead enable [reminders](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) on your calendar and set up a reminder  so that notification stays alive till you manually dismiss.

For more see [What is the difference between Events, Reminders and Tasks?](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/3263294/what-is-the-difference-between-events-reminders-and-tasks?hl=en) and
[What is the difference between a reminder and an event in Google Calendar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140571/131553)

Comment: If you still want to use events, you can mail yourself the [notification text](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226505/131553) and see the email unread notifications

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a workaround for this for some time - it's an app called [Events Notifier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.calendareventsnotifier) (I have no affiliation with the app). You turn off notifications from your calendar app and allow the notifier to present the notifications instead. The notifications will not disappear unless you explicitly dismiss them.